# Decrypting Fernet Ciphertext From MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

Hello I am trying to decrypt this cipher text which is stored on a MySQL server. I am using Fernet encryption from the module `cryptography`
In the program:

```
print(type(EncryptedMedicalInfo))
print(repr(EncryptedMedicalInfo))
```

Yield

```
<class 'str'>
'gAAAAABcKK-sVA50QhCQ128dXUNEBcFfHDhe5tZ26AlQnAAbmil42YrmtKLnuMbHtlnJSrqcWkCDxpRUfOO5tXiaaY1tqIqb6Q=='
```

The Key is `nqfL0heimeTwhZBZG70k0Ma9bmwe6UkSH0xpa_O7Mew=`

And the key is stored in the table as:
[image: MySQL key]

However when I do:

```
print(type(EncryptedMedicalInfo))
print(repr(EncryptedMedicalInfo))
b = bytes(EncryptedMedicalInfo, 'utf-8')
print(Ecy.decrypt(b))
```

I get:

```
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Ill include how the data is encrypted if that helps.

```
b = bytes(MedicalInfo, 'utf-8')
EcryptMedInfo= Ecy.encrypt(b)
```

Comment: Can you run `Ecy.decrypt(EcryptMedInfo)` first? (From: `EcryptMedInfo= Ecy.encrypt(b)`) From the documentation it looks like the decrypt method takes the output from the encrypt method. https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.decrypt

Comment: I get `b'None'`

Comment: And what is `MedicalInfo` in the encrypt statement?

Comment: The string `None` is encrypted to `b'gAAAAABcLknzBKCw2-7NIsu6e4gih8JQMDOCJCHIeYv5U_VAfN-Z2WqBz16jdM3qp5pTT6082JrHYbIr-1hD4x_CE1Nu1RuDSw=='`

Comment: So it decrypted successfully?

Comment: No I was just stating that MedicalInfo="None"

Comment: If `MedicalInfo` was `b'None'` and it decrypted as `b'None'` - then that sounds like it has worked. Try changing the value of `MedicalInfo` to confirm that's the case.